# I am facing a problem with my database schema

Tags: mysql, database

I am facing a problem with my database schema. Example I have to create **mail models** with dynamic fields each model will have at least fields common to the others (sender, recipient, date, subject).

[image]

Now the user can create several different models. Example :**model purchase mail** is different from **model request mail**.

[image]

Now when registering mail model to database, do i need to create a table with all the fields the user will create and add fields to the table whenever the model changes? or need to create a table for each model mail.

Comment: or a column in the single table to hold the model name ?

Comment: even with that I risk having a hundred columns

Comment: then there maybe other design improvements possible

Comment: Yes it is possible

Comment: will the number of columns in the database affect the performance during selections and requests on this table?